# Display XML from a String in iframe as XMLTree

Tags: javascript, html, xml, iframe

I got an XML String from a gwt rpc call which i want to embed as xml page into an iframe. What i hope to see is the pretty printed xml tree with its collapsible structure the browsers offer surrounded by normal html stuff. So to say an inpage view of the xml.

I cannot use the srcdoc attribute of iframes because its not supported by IE8 (earliest needed to support) and the next problem is that no javascript libraries are allowed.

What I tried:

```
var iframeDocument = document.querySelector('#foo').contentWindow.document;
iframeDocument.open('text/xml', 'replace'); // Also tested without Args
iframeDocument.write(xmlcontent);
iframeDocument.close();
```

While Firefox atleast shows the XML tags but unformatted and without tree Chrome and IE remove the html tags and just lineup the contents.

Nextthing i tried is

```
<iframe id="xmlframe" src="test.xml" name="thexml">
```

Here Firefox does exactly what I want while the others produce the same output as before. So this is also not working and well i don't have the test.xml i just have a string variable along with other stuff returned...

Is this even possible? If not how would you open a new popup with the xml String as content?

Comment: any solution on this yet?

Comment: No I found no Solution for this. Every browser handles this differently and it seems not possible to force the browser to parse a xml as xml in an iframe. I also tested around with dataurl inside iframes to achive this. So I came up with a normal xml download which normaly opens in a popup for this.

Comment: how about escaping '<' and '>' by '&lt;' and '&gt;'?

Answer (score 2):

Like L.Monty said in the comments i would replace every `<` in your XML-string with `&lt;` and every `>` with `&gt;` so that the browser doesn't try to interpret all the tags as HTML.

For your tree-like view i would write my own function which adds a break after each XML end tag + an amount of spaces which you can count in a variable for each following XML-open tag. Dont Forget to reduce this Counter for each XML-Close tag as well.